# How to validate one key based on another in Colander Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pylons, colander

I am using [Colander](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/basics.html) for validation, and would like to validate one key based on another.

e.g:
I would like to validate field value based on entity value:

```
class ValidationSchema(Validator.MappingSchema):
    entity = Validator.SchemaNode(Validator.String())
    field = Validator.SchemaNode(Validator.String(), missing=Validator.drop)

try:
    values = {"entity":"a", "field":"field1"}
    parameters = ValidationSchema().deserialize()
except Validator.Invalid as e:
    errors = e.asdict()
    return
```

If entity is `a` then field should be `field1` 
If entity is `b` then field should be `field2` 
If entity is not present then do not validate field key

How can this be implemented?